# Use of Halite Keys in new PHP 7.2 Sodium Functions

Tags: php, encryption, libsodium

We have a bunch of data that was encrypted on a PHP 7.1 installation using Halite, and the server was recently updated to 7.2, which libsodium is now part of PHP.  We have our key files (public and secret) that consist of 200 characters (showing an old test public key below for demonstration):

`31400100d6c01eb5744a3b508b389a2b10e4b554f8f004f8a0afc78beb02f574bbf2d8017563a641bd508e6a3c132e3350bf1bd1bdf402115b2a628dd63cf5cf5dae1fedbe6e4bc2b5e58c372c3bd960fada57741ef204a9a19a767f126af653a60d5be0`

They were generated using the following code:

```
$encryptionKey = KeyFactory::generateEncryptionKey();
KeyFactory::save($encryptionKey, $keyPath . $keyPublic);
```

We used to encrypt/decrypt like so (of course never on same server):

```
$webPublicKey = KeyFactory::loadEncryptionPublicKey($keyPath . $keyPublic);
$encrypted = Asymmetric::seal($string,$webPublicKey);

$webSecretKey = KeyFactory::loadEncryptionSecretKey($keyPath . $keySecret);
$decrypted = Asymmetric::unseal($encrypted,$webSecretKey);
```

How do we use these keys generated in a previous version of libsodium/halite to decrypt our existing data now that we are on PHP 7.2?  Trying to use the old keys in the new `sodium_` functions in PHP7.2 continually results in errors about key length.

I appreciate any guidance you can provide.

Thanks!

Comment: Looking at [the documentation of Halite's `KeyFactory`](https://github.com/paragonie/halite/blob/v4.4.2/doc/Classes/KeyFactory.md), it says for `generateEncryptionKey()`: "Generate an encryption key (symmetric-key cryptography).". But you write you are using it with Asymmetric cryptography algorithms. That is not clear.

Comment: Also, your terminology of "secret" versus "private" key is confusing. The term "secret key" is typically used for symmetric cryptography. The term "private key" is used, often in conjunction with its associated "public key", when talking about asymmetric cryptography.

Comment: The functions `loadEncryptionPublicKey()` and `loadEncryptionSecretKey()` that you mention are nowhere to be found in the Halite documentation.

Comment: Right. The `loadEncryptionKeyPair()` method is for asymmetric cryptography. You can, from the `KeyPair` object, invoke `getSecretKey()` to get the private key object (we use secret instead of private for NaCl nomenclature compatibility reasons). `getRawKeyMaterial()` gets you the raw binary key.

Comment: Sorry guys, I understand the above, and I apologize I wasn't clear.  However, the fact is (even if `generateEncryptionKey()` was used incorrectly) that the old keys were used in the seal/unseal functions.  Is there a way to decrypt the data using the new sodium functions?